# Updating PYTHONPATH variable pointing to a dropbox directory containing a space

Tags: python, macos, bash, github, dropbox

I'm trying to import a module for python that I have written that is contained in a Dropbox folder whose path contains a space. Following the comments [here](http://www.bdnyc.org/2012/09/17/editing-pythonpath-to-import-modules/), I don't want to do a sys.path.append(path_to_repository) every time I use python, I'd rather just update my bash profile to point to the correct Dropbox folder once.

I've tried adapting the code from the previous page by appending the following lines to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
PYTHONPATH ="/Users/myusername/Dropbox (projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME"
export ${PYTHONPATH}
```

When I close the terminal window and reopen, I get the following error message:

```
-bash: PYTHONPATH: command not found
-bash: export: `/Users/myusername/Dropbox': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME': not a valid identifier
```

and (not suprisingly) when I then try to import from the repository in python, I get a module not found:

```
>>> from REPOSITORY_NAME import myfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named REPOSITORY_NAME
```

Does anyone have any solutions?
Some questions/possibilities I'm thinking of -

1) Does it have anything to do with my Anaconda configuration? (Anaconda runs in a virtual env)

2) Does it has anything to do with the folder with python code being installed in Dropbox?

3) Could it be that spaces in pythonpath are not interpreted correctly?

4) Is there any problem with this being the same directory that syncs to github and bitbucket?

Thanks in advance for your help.

*Edit:

The solution seems to be to 1) erase the extra space in the first line and 2) repalce the ${PYTHONPATH} with PYTHONPATH in the second line, i.e. to adjust ~/.bash_profile to have the following line:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Users/myusername/Dropbox (projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Is your path correct?

Comment: Yes, if I do cd "/Users/myusername/Dropbox (projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME" in terminal, I "land" in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago. The error message is indicating that the problem lies in the space in the directory path - the bash_profile is being truncated by the space and it is splitting the path into 2. It may be a problem with the way bash handles spaces, but I am not 100% sure.

Here is one solution that worked for me:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/myusername/Dropbox (projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME"
```

It is similar to what you have, but  export and PYTHONPATH are in the same line. I don't think this would interfere with Dropbox, Github, Bitbucket, Anaconda (or any other virtualenv like Enthought) etc., as long as you as have a _init__.py' file in each directory where you have your .py files.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. Have no idea why, though - why does doing it in one line rather than two solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you put a space before the `=` sign when exporting `PYTHONPATH`:

```
PYTHONPATH ="/Users/myusername/Dropbox (projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME"
```

Should be:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Users/myusername/Dropbox (projectname)/REPOSITORY_NAME"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Unfortunately this gets rid of just the first error, i.e. when I fix the space, close the terminal and reopen, the first of the three errors no longer occur, but I'm still getting the latter two errors.

Comment: @ericthegreat: Is that _exactly_ what you have in your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Just accepted the answer from @LMNYC - if I change the export PYTHONPATH to be on the same line it works, no idea why.

Comment: @ericthegreat: It shouldn't matter if the `export` is on the same line or not.

Comment: you are totally right, and your last question was correct, I was originally doing export ${PYTHONPATH} which was causing the error, and not export PYTHONPATH. Sorry about that, and many thanks.